# How to set a readonly property?

Tags: asp.net

Can you say how to set readonly property in property method(get and set).

Answer (score 4):

You can either only give your property a getter:

```
private string _name;

public string Name { get { return _name; } }
```

Or you can give the accessors different visibilities:

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply omit the setter:

```
 private string myField;
 public string MyReadOnlyProperty {get { return myField;}}
```